# How to get an attribute with SimpleXML?

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm using `simplexml_load_file($path_xml_file)`, it works good!

If I do `print_r($xml)` it prints:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [Message] => Login Successful
            [Token] => 11111111111
            [DataFormat] => CSV

        )
)
```

How Can I get "token" value?

Thank you!