# PHP for XML with namespaces and attributes

Tags: php, xml

I've been playing arround nearly all day for getting attributes of xml item which is is namespaces. Part of XML:
...

```
<item>
      <title>name</title>
      <link>link</link>
      <media:thumbnail url="url" height="133" width="200"  />
</item>
```

...
What I managed to get is title and link with following script:

```
$z = new XMLReader;
$z->open($gLink);
$doc = new DOMDocument;
while ($z->read() && $z->name !== 'item');
$node = simplexml_import_dom($doc->importNode($z->expand(), true));
$gTitle = $node->title;
$gLink = $node->link;
$gThumb = $node->children('media', true)->thumbnail->children();
print_r($gThumb);
```

After printing $gThumb I get:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( [@attributes] => Array ( [url] => url [height] => 133 [width] => 200 ) )
```

And what I need to get is url from attribute. I would be very pleased to get any help.

Comment: Bet what I can not modify xml because it is taken from some RSS

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get an attribute with SimpleXML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410520/how-to-get-an-attribute-with-simplexml)

Comment: `print_r($gThumb->xpath('@url'));
echo (string)$gThumb['url'];`
isn't working too

Comment: if `echo (string) $gThumb['url'];` isnt working, you are doing something else wrong. In that case, provide a reproducable example.

Comment: For the (string)$gThumb['url']; have you removed the ->children() from the end of $gThumb = $node->children('media', true)->thumbnail->children(); before doing this? Just trying to eliminate any of the more obvious errors.

Comment: I would just like to point out that you should be very skeptical at all times with printing out (print_r) or dumping (var_dump) data from a simpleXML object because in many situations I have found that it does NOT always show you everything it holds. This is because simpleXML returns references to resources, and print_r doesn't work perfectly on them at all times. Granted it does work a lot of the time, there have been many situations where deeply nested nodes weren't showing at all with a print_r, but if I discriminated deeper into the object they would. I'd keep this in mind at all times!

Answer (score 3):

If its a SimpleXMLElement then use

```
$foo = (string)$gThumb->attributes()->url
```