# Extract Tag Attribute Content From XML

Tags: php, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get an attribute with SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410520/how-to-get-an-attribute-with-simplexml)

I've a XML file which is stored as a PHP variable.

I've to extract tags `addr` & `status` value as a PHP variable from the xml string.

How to process it? It is dynamic and XML Tag attributes count also will be changing.

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0"?>
<results>
<tags addr="http://a.com" status="yes">
<www addr="http://b.com" status="" status_source=""/>
<www addr="http://c.com" status="yes" status_source="None"/>
</tags>
<tags addr="http://d.com" status="no">
<www addr="http://e.com" status="" status_source=""/>
</tags>
<tags addr="http://f.com" status="no"/></tags>
<tags addr="http://g.com" status="no"/></tags>
</results>';
```

Comment: *(related)* [Best XML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/188414/best-xml-parser-for-php/3616044#3616044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using DOMDocument class you can make PHP read the XML and then look for the tag elements in it
http://php.net/DOMDocument

Example

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);

$tags = $document->getElementsByTagName("www");
...
```

Comment: Thanks @SparK at-Gordon That Worked..:)