# Is there any way to use a preg expression to search string and put in array? PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, split

Ive been trying to use `preg_split` but it's not working very well, this is how I'm using it:

```
$html_str = '<span class="spanClass" rel="rel span">Text Span</span>';

$arrTemp = preg_split('/\<span class=\"spanClass\" rel=\"(.+?)\"\>(.+?)\<\/span\>/', $html_str);
```

So I would get this 2 `'(.+?)'` variables into an `array(span rel and Text Span)`.

I'm probably not thinking about it in the best possible way to solve my problem, but the fact is that my string will have more than one `<span>` mixed with trash html and I need to separate only the `<span>` content in an array. Any better ideas?

Comment: @Diogo: why not using all those wonderful features like DomDocument or simplexml, would be simpler no?

Comment: @RageZ Simplexml would only work for valid XHTML. Only DOM can parse broken HTML.

Comment: @Gordon: good remark but nothing that tidy wouldn't help ;-)

Comment: @Phil the linked answer does not explain why you do not want to use Regex for parsing HTML at all. It's just a rant that got too many upvotes due to funny characters. Worst of all, it's wrong: PHP's Regex engine uses PCRE and that can parse HTML. I'm all for using a DOM parser, but in all fairness, whether to use Regex or a Parser depends on the complexity of the markup you want to parse.

Comment: possible duplicate of [extract tag attribute from xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7886267/extract-tag-attribute-content-from-xml) and [grabbing th href attribute of an a element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820666/grabbing-the-href-attribute-of-an-a-element/3820783#3820783)

Comment: @Gordon That answer was good enough to inspire an [entire article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) from Jeff. Perhaps that is a better link. Still not sure why my comment was flagged

Answer (score 0):

First of all preg_split is the wrong function, you really meant preg_match from the syntax of regex that you seem to be using.

Correct use would be:

```
$html = '<span class="spanClass" rel="foo bar">Text Span</span>';
preg_match("/<span.*rel=[\"']([^\"']+)[\"'][^>]*>([^<]+)<\/span>/", $html, &$A);
print_r($A);
```

This outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <span class="spanClass" rel="foo bar">Text Span</span>
    [1] => foo bar
    [2] => Text Span
)
```

So above uses preg_match; $A[0] contains the entire line $A[1] the rel= stuff and $A[2] the Text Span stuff.