# Parse XML link with PHP

Tags: php, html, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I have an XML feed that looks something like this:

[image: xml]

I can parse the title easily enough using simpleXML:

```
$pictureBoxXMLFeed = simplexml_load_file('https://www.picturebox.tv/xml/feeds/FindAnyFilm/FindAnyFilm.xml');;

echo $pictureBoxXMLFeed->entry[1]->title;

foreach($pictureBoxXMLFeed->entry as $value){

    echo $value->title;
    echo '<br/>';

}
```

But I need to grab the link element in the feed which looks something like this:

```
<link href="http://www.picturebox.tv/watchnow?id=UKIC30" rel="alternate"/>
```

FYI, this doesn't work:

echo $value->link;

Thanks for any help...

Comment: Define "doesn't work" - does it just not show anything or does it throw an error?

Comment: doesn't show anything, it highlights as echo does in DreamWeaver leading me to believe it's reserved?

Comment: If the root element of the XML is entry, then you don't need to address it.  What happens with echo $pictureBoxXMLFeed->link->attributes()->href;

Comment: `$value->link` works perfectly. The *element* is empty though, so what should the output be? If you are after the href *attribute*, then a look at [SimpleXml Example #5 in the PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) will tell you need to use `$value->link['href'];`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get attribute with SimpleXml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410520/how-to-get-an-attribute-with-simplexml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
$string = '
<entry>
    <link href="http://www.picturebox.tv/watchnow?id=UKIC30" rel="alternate"/>
</entry>';

$simpleXML = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($simpleXML->link->attributes() as $name => $value) {
    echo $name.': '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

Gives:

```
href: http://www.picturebox.tv/watchnow?id=UKIC30
rel: alternate
```

Answer (score 1):

In each of the $value, it is a simplexml_element, you an href is an attribute, so you need to do a check on

```
foreach ($value->attributes as $a) {
  if ($a->getName() == "href") { do something; }
}
```

or `$value->{"href"};`
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$pictureBoxXMLFeed = simplexml_load_file('https://www.picturebox.tv/xml/feeds/FindAnyFilm/FindAnyFilm.xml');;

foreach($pictureBoxXMLFeed->entry[1] as $value){
    if($value->getName() == 'link') {
    echo $value->asXML();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

href is an attribute, so :

```
foreach($pictureBoxXMLFeed->entry as $value){
    echo $value->link['href'];
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

or

```
foreach($pictureBoxXMLFeed->entry as $value){
    echo $value->link->attributes()->href;
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this:

```
$pictureBoxXMLFeed = simplexml_load_file('https://www.picturebox.tv/xml/feeds/FindAnyFilm/FindAnyFilm.xml',LIBXML_NOEMPTYTAG);
```

Then see if `link` comes through...

Comment: The file's being loaded into Simple XML just fine. He's trying to retrieve an attribute through incorrect access.