# How can I retrieve values from xml if the node has attributes?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get an attribute with SimpleXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410520/how-to-get-an-attribute-with-simplexml)

How can I get the values of height,length,weight and width? since it has attributes on it? In other values I have no problem in retrieving it, just this values has attributes.

Note:The height,length,weight and width part is only the problem

Here's How I retrieve it:

```
$from_amazon = array(
   'asin'     => $item->ASIN,
   'product_name'
              => $item->ItemAttributes->Title, 
   'image'    => $item->SmallImage->URL,
   'price'    => $item->ItemAttributes->ListPrice->FormattedPrice, 
   'product_description'
              => $item->EditorialReviews->EditorialReview->Content,
   'category' => $item->ItemAttributes->ProductGroup,
   'weight'   => $item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Weight
);
```

[image: XML DOM]

Comment: Try again, see the changes in the line of code in the answer below. If you want to learn more, you should to read the manual about simplexml, it has some basic examples: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php that contains everything you need to know. Especially *Example #5 Using attributes* has what you're looking for.

Comment: in my response the weight value is like this "weight":{"@attributes":{"Units":"hundredths-pounds"},"0":"420"}}

Comment: Okay, then try: `'weight'   => (string) $item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Weight`. The important part is to *cast to string*, see the `(string)` in front of the `$item->...`. Actually, this is a different duplicate.

Comment: @hakra yey it works! yo save me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplexml library will return you the object for that node. But you only want it's text. Therefore you need to cast it to string:

```
'weight'   => (string) $item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Weight
              ^^^^^^^^
```

That will give you the text as string of that XML node.

---

In the [Simplexml documentation<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) you find that in *Example #6 Comparing Elements and Attributes with Text*:

> To compare an element or attribute with a string or pass it into a function that requires a string, you must cast it to a string using (string). Otherwise, PHP treats the element as an object.
>
> ```
> (string) $movies->movie->title
> ```

Answer (score 1):

It looks you are using SimpleXML to parse the data.
You can look [here](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) on how you can get the attributes.

In your case it will look like

```
$item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Weight->attributes()->Units
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

Comment: @hakra Yes, but in his structure he has `Units` attribute of `Width` which is not what the code says now. I think either mine example should be fixed to match question XML or the question XML should be clarified.

Comment: it has warning and in my response weight: null?

Comment: @SuiGo I've written it originally as `$item->ItemAttributes->PackageDimensions->Weight->attributes()->Units`. Please try it.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object

Comment: @SuiGo Then probably you should update the question with the correct XML. For example in your code you shown `$item->ItemAttributes->Title` but in your XML there's no `Title` tag in `ItemAttributes`.

Comment: Thanks you for helping me appreciate it :)