# How can I print specific content of a child node with XPATH in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have an XPATH query I am running in PHP against the following XML from CWE:

```
<Weaknesses>
<Weakness ID="211" Name="Test" Weakness_Abstraction="Base" Status="Incomplete">
<Description>
<Description_Summary>
The software performs an operation that triggers an external diagnostic or error message that is not directly generated by the software, such as an error generated by the programming language interpreter that the software uses. The error can contain sensitive system information.
</Description_Summary>
</Description>
</Weakness>
</Weaknesses>
```

I have written the following PHP with XPATH in order to target the content within the "Description_Summary" child node, however, it simply returns Array(). I have a $_GET which pulls the $searchString variable from the previous page, pointing to my specific attribute found within the "Weakness" node.

```
<?php
$searchString = $_GET["searchString"];
echo "<b>CWE Name: </b>" . $searchString . "</br>";
$xml = simplexml_load_file("cwe.xml");

$description = $xml->xpath('//Weakness[@Name="'. $searchString .'"]/Description/Description_Summary/text()');

echo "<pre>"; print_r($description); echo "</pre>";

?>
```

What it currently returns:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
        )

)
```

What is wrong with my print statement or XPATH query? Thanks!

Comment: is this a typo: `Description/Description_Text/text()`?  Did you mean to use `Description/Description_Summary/text()`?

Comment: Yes, thank you Joe, it is a typo. I will correct that.

Comment: your xpath query looks fine, are you sure yout $searchString is 'Test'.

Comment: I am certain, as when I remove /Description_Summary/text() it returns the sub nodes and content found within Description. Am I printing out the array incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your code. With some modifications to read from a string, I tested this on [codepad and it worked fine](http://codepad.org/bMIDfxrg).

```
<?php
$xml = '<Weaknesses>
<Weakness ID="211" Name="Test" Weakness_Abstraction="Base" Status="Incomplete">
<Description>
<Description_Summary>
The software performs an operation that triggers an external diagnostic or error message that is not directly generated by the software, such as an error generated by the programming language interpreter that the software uses. The error can contain sensitive system information.
</Description_Summary>
</Description>
</Weakness>
</Weaknesses>';

$searchString = 'Test';
echo "<b>CWE Name: </b>" . $searchString . "</br>";
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$description = $xml->xpath('//Weakness[@Name="'. $searchString .'"]/Description/Description_Summary/text()');

echo "<pre>"; print_r((string) $description[0]); echo "</pre>";

?>
```

And returns this:

```
<b>CWE Name: </b>Test</br><pre>
The software performs an operation that triggers an external diagnostic or error message that is not directly generated by the software, such as an error generated by the programming language interpreter that the software uses. The error can contain sensitive system information.
</pre>
```

It is probably the case that the file doesn't contain what you think it does, or the `$searchString` isn't equal to `Test`.

Comment: Interesting, I see. Well, let me paste a full example of a Weakness stanza in pastebin and maybe you can tell me if I am missing something. Found here: http://pastebin.com/pKZpw3qQ

As a side-question, if I wanted to print only the string found within SimpleXMLElement Object, how would I go about that?

Comment: The second bit is easy, just cast the Object to a string. I can edit that into the answer.

Comment: The former: With the right argument to the XPath still seems to work - http://codepad.org/YlZRQDok Is there a chance an incorrect `$searchString` is being given?

Comment: There must be something simple that I am messing up on as I have been hardcoding the string "Test" for both the attribute as well as placing it within the XPath query. I guess I will have to take another look as you have already proven yourself correct many times! Thanks again, though!

Comment: Apparently the way I was loading the XML file was incorrect? Once I changed it to the full path with the file instead of simply the filename, it started working! Weird, eh? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> What is wrong with my print statement.

Looks not too-wrong but has some problems. First you could reduce it to a single expression perhaps:

```
echo "<pre>", print_r($description, true), "</pre>";
```

but this is merely cosmetic. The other thing that looks wrong is that you're using `print_r` on a `SimpleXMLElement`. Both [`print_r` and `var_dump` do not work well with simplexml](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16119597/367456) because of the magic those objects have.

Instead just echo them out as XML, this should be most descriptive:

```
echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($description[0]->asXML()), "</pre>";
```

Exemplary output (plain text):

```
<pre>&lt;Description_Summary&gt;
The software performs an operation that triggers an external diagnostic or error message that is not directly generated by the software, such as an error generated by the programming language interpreter that the software uses. The error can contain sensitive system information.
&lt;/Description_Summary&gt;</pre>
```

This already shows that you didn't query any text-nodes here but an element. Read on why.

> What's wrong with my XPath query?

You are using the simplexml extenstion. It has *limited* xpath support by what it can return. As your example shows, invoking the `xpath()` method does not fail, however, in the return array, there are no text-nodes because [a SimpleXMLElement can not be a text-node](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557961/367456).

Therefore having an XPath expression that queries for text-nodes like you did (`... text()`) is kinda wrong.