# Can't convert string into XML object

Tags: php, xml

I have a valid xml code in a string format. I would like to convert the string into an XML object.

```
$string = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<d:multistatus xmlns:d="DAV:" xmlns:nc="http://example.com" xmlns:oc="http://example.com" xmlns:s="http://example.com">
   <d:response>
      <d:href>/remote.php/dav/files/test3.txt</d:href>
      <d:propstat>
         <d:prop>
            <d:getlastmodified>Tue, 03 Dec 2019 12:42:33 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
            <d:resourcetype>
               <d:collection />
            </d:resourcetype>
            <d:quota-used-bytes>1942356098</d:quota-used-bytes>
            <d:quota-available-bytes>-3</d:quota-available-bytes>
            <d:getetag>"5de6583924a4b"</d:getetag>
         </d:prop>
         <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
      </d:propstat>
   </d:response>
   <d:response>
      <d:href>/remote.php/dav/files/test2.txt</d:href>
      <d:propstat>
         <d:prop>
            <d:getlastmodified>Thu, 21 Nov 2019 11:30:59 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
            <d:resourcetype>
               <d:collection />
            </d:resourcetype>
            <d:quota-used-bytes>130</d:quota-used-bytes>
            <d:quota-available-bytes>-3</d:quota-available-bytes>
            <d:getetag>"5dd675741bdcb"</d:getetag>
         </d:prop>
         <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
      </d:propstat>
      <d:propstat>
         <d:prop>
            <d:getcontentlength />
            <d:getcontenttype />
         </d:prop>
         <d:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</d:status>
      </d:propstat>
   </d:response>
   <d:response>
      <d:href>/remote.php/dav/files/test.txt</d:href>
      <d:propstat>
         <d:prop>
            <d:getlastmodified>Wed, 27 Nov 2019 10:47:45 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
            <d:getcontentlength>1942355968</d:getcontentlength>
            <d:resourcetype />
            <d:getetag>"aa05cb48be85a3c306421807c2467acf"</d:getetag>
            <d:getcontenttype>application/octet-stream</d:getcontenttype>
         </d:prop>
         <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
      </d:propstat>
      <d:propstat>
         <d:prop>
            <d:quota-used-bytes />
            <d:quota-available-bytes />
         </d:prop>
         <d:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</d:status>
      </d:propstat>
   </d:response>
   <d:response>
      <d:href>/remote.php/dav/files/openSUSE-Leap-42.3-DVD-x86_64.iso/</d:href>
      <d:propstat>
         <d:prop>
            <d:getlastmodified>Wed, 27 Nov 2019 10:31:51 GMT</d:getlastmodified>
            <d:resourcetype>
               <d:collection />
            </d:resourcetype>
            <d:quota-used-bytes>0</d:quota-used-bytes>
            <d:quota-available-bytes>-3</d:quota-available-bytes>
            <d:getetag>"5de6309233431"</d:getetag>
         </d:prop>
         <d:status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</d:status>
      </d:propstat>
      <d:propstat>
         <d:prop>
            <d:getcontentlength />
            <d:getcontenttype />
         </d:prop>
         <d:status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</d:status>
      </d:propstat>
   </d:response>
</d:multistatus>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump($xml);
```

Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (0) {
}
```

I don't understand why I have a blank result.

Comment: This behaviour is expected - it's more a limitation of `var_dump()` than SimpleXML - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16119597/dont-understand-the-output-in-xml-entities-and-php-simplexmlelement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just how it is supposed to be, the data is still there, you just need to use the SimpleXML methods to get what you need, for [demo](https://3v4l.org/iiKe0) try this:

```
<?php

$string = <<<XML
YOUR XML
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
var_dump($xml->getName());
```

Comment: How do you extract `/remote.php/dav/files/test3.txt` for e.g. ?